# Use Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER) with some grammar expression matching

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

In my documents,all of sentences is builder with this specific grammar expression:A:person B:location C:work.
If I want to extract named entities(Tom:PERSON), how to do that?.
I have used [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml), but I can not find a huge data to train a classifier and I don't want to do that.So we can find entities by other ways?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The NER system should extract people out-of-the-box already; see the documentation for how. Are you trying to re-train the NER system on a new set of people? Or, do you have a custom list of people / locations / work that you'd like to annotate?

Comment: Yes.I have a new set of people and a custom list of entities.I have trained for a new classifier,but it can not work with some name which dont see in trained data.If we need trained all of possible name,i thinh i can not do that.

Comment: All statistical systems will have some accuracy under 100%. How often is it missing names not in the training data? If your data is sufficiently large (10k+ tokens or so), you should recognize over 4 in 5 names correctly.